# Option for making an edit a comment

Tags: feature-request, comments, suggested-edits, convert-to-comment

One of the reasons for rejecting an edit is that it should be a comment.

I propose that if the reviewer feels that that that is the case, they should be able to make it a comment.

For anonymous edits, I suppose that community or someone would take ownership.

Thoughts?

Comment: It's just not feasible: Too much work for too little gain. It might look easy in the diff, but it will be hard work to extract the edited part from the post (imagine edits that aren't standalone paragraphs — the [diff calculations are difficult enough as it is](http://meta.superuser.com/questions/3835/differences-between-plain-text-diff-and-formatted-diff)).

Comment: To simplify, only allow it if it is a standalone paragraph. It does not make any sense otherwise.

Comment: See my link. The edit could easily have been a standalone paragraph (it's arbitrary if you add two newlines before an addition), and one of the diffs just failed to recognize it. It's just too many restrictions on a feasible implementation to make it useful, as well as understandable to non-technical people. This would affect sites like Cooking.SE, where not everybody is a programmer or computer geek.

Comment: Could you provide some examples of when this actually happens?

Comment: [Example of such an edit](http://superuser.com/suggested-edits/7693) that could have been a comment. Although I think it would have been fine to just accept it.

Answer (score 3):

Anonymous users don't need to be leaving comments. There's also no one to follow up with any clarification triggered, so it's pointless.

There's not that many instances where a suggested edit needs to be a comment and that the comment is worth making in the first place.

Letting these comments fall through is no worth catching.

Comment: There are instances where the added content to the answer in unverifiable, which gives the tendency to reject as not to change the intention to the original post. These however can be useful and are worthy as a comment. Perhaps adding a close reason "should be a comment" might be a solution in between...

Comment: @TomWijsman Still, nothing prevents you from adding the comment yourself. I just think that there's no practical way of "converting" an addition (Should it be a paragraph? What about two? Could you edit it before to make it stand alone, etc?).